# Overstay Student Visa in Italy

Tags: us-citizens, italy, student-visas

We applied for a student visa for my daughter to study in Italy.  Among other things, we gave them copies of her tickets home.  Her flight home is on 31st December 2022.  We have only now looked carefully at the visa and see it expires on 16th of December.  We have tickets to fly to visit her on 19th December.  We plan to all fly home together on 31st of December.  We are all US citizens and home is USA.
If she leaves with us on 31st, two weeks after visa expires, will she have a big problem leaving?  What if she wants to visit Italy again to travel or study?  If in the future she applied for another student visa or even a work permit in Italy, would a two week overstay cause her a big problem?
If she were to want to travel to Italy again, it would not be for nine months or more.

Would going to London for a couple of days then coming back to Italy help?

I've looked at a few other questions and answers and do not see exactly this situation.

Comment: @ Traveller It sort of answers but only if it is correct.  The other answers to that question suggest the issue might not be clear and may depend on which country in the Schengen area you're talking about.   But it is very helpful.  I'll read that answer carefully and think it over before I accept or not.  Thanks.

Comment: @DJClayworth  I don't think your edit is correct.  A visa is a thing like a car or a passport or a croissant.  In the middle of a sentence, it does not need to be capitalized.  Capitalized as in 'my VISA was declined and I had to borrow money from my date' refers to the credit card.  In a title, the first letter could be capitalized.  I'll fix the title of the question to "Overstay Student Visa ..."

Comment: Will you leave the Schengen area from Italy?

Comment: @xngtng Yes.  On Dec 31 she will leave Milan to fly to USA.

Comment: Is the expiry date for the visa or her residence permit? Did she apply for a residence permit after arriving in Italy with the visa (which should be of type D)?

Comment: @xngtng Just has been studying and living on the student visa.  She has not applied for any new visas or extensions.  The expiry date is her student visa.

Comment: When did she start her studies, more than three months ago? Also did she apply for a residence permit? If she was in italy for more than 3 months, she should have applied for a residence permit.

Comment: If she had a type D visa she was supposed to apply for a residence permit within 8 days of her arrival, if she had not done that, it is better that she leaves before the expiry of the visa via another Schengen country... If she does not have a type D visa (although it would be strange to issue a C visa to a US citizen when it is not needed), then the 90/180 rules apply and no extension is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Overstaying can never be recommended as a good idea. Your daughter could be fined upon exiting the Schengen Area, but fines for minor immigration-related offences are often waived (if the foreigner leaves voluntarily).

> Would going to London for a couple of days then coming back to Italy help?

It would, especially if she manages to leave the Schengen Area before her visa expires. If she only gets to the UK after a few days' overstay, it's probably better to book her a flight to the US directly from the UK, instead of her having to return back to the Schengen Area first.

> What if she wants to visit Italy again to travel or study?

Yes, an overstay **might** negatively affect her future visits or visa applications, but probably not permanently. Since the US is a low-risk country in terms of illegal immigration to the Schengen Area, it's not likely she'll be permanently banned from entering it. IMHO (not an expert opinion), I'd wait at least a year before attempting to enter the Schengen Area again, either as a tourist or as a student.